# Dragging force layout nodes by dragging their labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, force-layout

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SYc5a/) example, one can drag nodes by grabbing node *symbols*, but not by grabbing node *labels*, even though for both there is this code line:

```
call(force.drag);
```

Why? How to enable user to drag nodes by dragging their labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is corrected example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4zSh/). The mistake was that there was CSS line `pointer-events: none;` in original code that prevented dragging by dragging labels.